# Headphone similar to Sennheiser PX95

Tags: audio, headphones

I love my [Sennheiser PX95](https://www.head-fi.org/showcase/sennheiser-px-95-versatile-on-ear-headphones.16577/) that I bought two years ago. It's simple. Lightweight yet sturdy with its metal frame. Does not over-heat your eats. The sound is more than decent. And it... *used to* be cheap ($35 back in the days).

Now Sennheiser seems to have discontinued the production of the PX95, and you can only buy it second-hand for about $75.

Is any other manufacturer making headphones similar to the PX95 these days?

Specifically, I am looking for headphones:

1. Under $40.
2. Overhead,
3. Lightweight,
4. ``Open-ears", i.e., with speaker that do not cover the whole ear and avoid overheating your ears.
5. Sturdy, ideally with a *metal frame* (I have been throwing my PX95 in my backpack without much care for more than 2 years, and it's like new, no damage to the frame, the speakers, or the cord),
6. That provide a decent sound for the price, comparable or just as good as the PX95 (I realize this item is harder to evaluate...)
7. Mini-jack,
8. Corded,

?